# ¿Cómo realizar una llamada Ajax en IE 11?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer, get

Hice una llamada Ajax y funciona correctamente desde el chrome, pero al hacer la llamada desde  IE 11 el Ajax no funciona.

```
var $ = {
    ajax: function (url, success) {
        requestServer("get", url, success)
    },
    send: function (url, success, text) {
        requestServer("post", url, success, text)
    }    
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te aparece?

Comment: Como tal no sale un error, lo que ocurre es que por medio del Ajax cargo una tabla con datos, en chrome o firefox la tabla carga normalmente, pero en IE 11 el Ajax no funciona, por lo tanto dicha tabla no carga los datos.

Comment: ¿Fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás usando `jQuery` utiliza este código:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://api.website.com/getData',      
   type: 'GET'
   error: function() {
      $('#info').html('<p>Hubo un error brother, hay que llamar a los magníficos de SOes</p>');
   },
   success: function(data) {
      var $title = $('<h1>').text(data.Titulo);
      var $description = $('<p>').text(data.Descripcion);
      $('#info')
         .append($title)
         .append($description);
   }      
});
```

Donde data.Titulo y data.Descripcion representan propiedades del JSON que retorna la url `http://api.website.com/getData`.

Answer (score 0):

AjaxLite usa el metodo clasico del AJAX con XMLHttpRequest, es compatible con cualquier navegador, no depende de jQuery ni de otra libreria. Es un plugin minimalista solo para ejecutar peticiones AJAX.

Lo puedes encontrar en [Github](https://github.com/yoet92/AjaxLite)

y puedes usarlo asi:

```
 AjaxLite({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            console.log("BIEN", data)
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log("ERROR")
        }
    })
```